# Opscenter 5 setup error on adding existing cluster

Tags: opscenter

I've got an existing Cassandra cluster (Datastax Community v2.1, Linux).  I've downloaded 2.0.10 on a separate box (Win) just to use Opscenter (v5).  I add ('manage') the existing cluster by simply adding one or more of the IP addresses of the nodes, but get the following error messages:

```
Error creating cluster: c is undefined

Error getting basic OpsCenter information: Unable to load http://opscenter.datastax.com/latest-version?1411551302156 status: 0
```

After that, the page goes black with no visible content.

I can see that Opscenter has detected all the nodes in the opscenterd.log file.  I can't see any errors or warnings (other than ignoring scheduled job...only with DSE) in the logfile either.  It generates a conf file for my cluster, and the last thing I see in the log file is:

```
2014-09-24 10:57:11+0100 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2014-09-24 10:57:11+0100 [preprod_group_a]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2014-09-24 10:57:11+0100 [] DEBUG: Persisting config file E:\Program Files\DataStax  Community\opscenter\conf\clusters\preprod_group_a.conf
2014-09-24 10:57:11+0100 []  INFO: Finished starting new cluster services for preprod_group_a
2014-09-24 10:57:11+0100 [preprod_group_a]  INFO: Stopping repair servic
```

After that, nothing.  Any ideas?

NB: if I install Opscenter on one of the Linux nodes, it runs fine - but we'd like to avoid this in a live environment

Comment: Does windows machine have a working internet connection? OpsCenter 5.0 has a bug that might cause this behaviour if it fails to perform the latest version check. OpsCenter 5.0.1 was released several days ago that addresses this issue, so you might try upgrading.

Comment: Arre - can't find the option to get the Windows version of 5.0.1 anywhere; 5.0.0 (the version I believe I have) came with the Datastax Community 2.0.10 install.  The Linux installation (2.1.0) came with Opscenter 5.0.1 though.  I may just wait for 2.1.0 to come out for Windows if you suspect there may be a bug with 5.0.0...

Comment: Right, there is no Windows package for OpsCenter 5.0.1 yet. Sorry for that. Once it gets released, could you try it and see if it fixes this problem?